# Maximum size allowed for dynamic_bitset from boost library

Tags: c++, boost

I have a use case where I need to create a bit map with size 2^64-1. After some reading and googling over on this topic, i have decided to use dynamic_bitset from the C++ boost library.

Should I be concerned over the large size of bit map ? I would like to get more thoughts on the performance impact for such a huge size on dynamic_bitset. Any other alternatives for dynamic_bitset with respect to this use case ?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't have enough memory to store 2^64-1 bits...

Comment: 2^64 bits, divided by 8 = 2,305,843,009,213,693,952 bytes. That's 2.3 million Terabytes. So yes, you should be concerned about the size of that.

Comment: Okay. I screwed it up pretty badly here. My requirement was not really to store 2^64 - 1 bits. I just need to maintain the running index for a particular resource ID. My question was wrong and it doesnt make much sense. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the size of `dynamic_bitset` is not limited by the library or by the c++ language itself but it is limited by your RAM size. So, `2^64-1` bits is about `2,305,843,009,213,693,952` bytes, or `2,3` million terabytes. I don't think that you have that much memory in your computer.